# Updating two select boxes with same information

Tags: javascript

I have two select boxes. Only the second select is being updated.
If I remove the `ff.add` the `tf.add` works.

```js
function copyToFrame(selectedOption) {

  if (selectedOption == "New") {
    var tf = document.getElementById("sCopyToFrame");
    var option = document.createElement("option");

    document.getElementById('copyToFrameCounter').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('copyToFrameCounter').value) + 1;
    option.text = "Frame " + document.getElementById('copyToFrameCounter').value;
    tf.add(option);

    var ff = document.getElementById("sCopyFromFrame");
    ff.add(option);
  }
}
```

```html
<INPUT type="hidden" id="copyToFrameCounter" value="0">
<p> Copy to frame:
  <select id="sCopyToFrame" onchange="copyToFrame(this.value);">
        <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
        <option>New</option>
      </select>
</p>
<p> Copy from frame:
  <select id="sCopyFromFrame">
        <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
        <option></option>
      </select>
</p>
```

Comment: Because you have created only one option element with document so it can add only to one.

Comment: See the console error when you use the snippet I made for you - then add relevant stuff to create a [mcve]

Comment: where "copyToFrameCounter" element?

Comment: I added in the missing copyToFrameCounter element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add new option to both of the drop downs, you need two elements

```
function copyToFrame(selectedOption){

    if(selectedOption == "New"){
        var tf = document.getElementById("sCopyToFrame");
        var tf_option = document.createElement("option");

        document.getElementById('copyToFrameCounter').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('copyToFrameCounter').value) + 1;
        tf_option.text = "Frame " + document.getElementById('copyToFrameCounter').value;
        tf.add(tf_option);

        var ff = document.getElementById("sCopyFromFrame");
        var ff_option = tf_option.cloneNode(true);
        ff.add(ff_option); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function copyToFrame(selectedOption) {

  if (selectedOption == "New") {
    var tf = document.getElementById("sCopyToFrame");
    var ff = document.getElementById("sCopyFromFrame");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var optionCopy = document.createElement("option");
    var cTFC = parseInt(document.getElementById('copyToFrameCounter').value) + 1 || 0;

    option.text = "Frame " + cTFC;
    optionCopy.text = "Frame " + cTFC;
    
    tf.add(option);
    ff.add(optionCopy);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="copyToFrameCounter" value="0">
<p> Copy to frame:
  <select id="sCopyToFrame" onchange="copyToFrame(this.value);">
        <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
        <option>New</option>
      </select>
</p>
<p> Copy from frame:
  <select id="sCopyFromFrame">
        <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
        <option></option>
      </select>
</p>
```

Comment: You need to copy the counter back